# How to improve Random forest regression prediction result

Tags: regression, geospatial, random-forest, prediction

I am working with parking occupancy prediction using machine learning random forest regression. I have 6 features, I have tried to implement the random forest model but the results are not good, As I am very new to this I do not know what kind of model is suitable for this kind of problem. My dataset is huge I have 47 million rows. I have also used Random search cv but I cannot improve the model. Kindly have a look at the code below and help to improve or suggest another model.

[Random forest regression](https://deepnote.com/project/Untitled-Python-Project-D6jNHahzTyCIYd_OcsM0bw/%2FUntitled2.ipynb/#00001-84c156d9-2ee1-4083-9db4-889ccf0c6e30)

The features used are extracted with the help of the location data of the parking lots with a buffer. Kindly help me to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your used variables are :
['restaurants_pts','population','res_percent','com_percent','supermarkt_pts', 'bank_pts']

The thing I see is, for a same Parking, those variables won't change, so the Regression will just predict the "average" occupancy of the parking. One of the key part of your problem seem to be that the occupancy is not the same at 5pm and at 4am...

I'd suggest you work on a time variable (ex : arrival) so it's usable.
Itself, the variable cannot be understood by the model, but you can work on it to create categories with it. For example, you make a preprocess selecting only the HOUR of your variable, and then make categories with it (either each hour being a category, or larger categories like ['noon - 6am', '6am - 10am', '10am - 2pm', '2pm - 6 pm', '6 pm - noon'])

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So, the suggestion is to use the time variables by categorizing the time. The doubt I have is whether that will be in a single column like other variables? Kindly apologize me for the basic questions I am very new to this.

Comment: Even if it's not a single column, that's no big deal. Just try to avoid having many many colums so the variable doesn't take everything for itself. As I said, you can make manual categories with hour, and then use One Hot Encoder, to create binary variables. 5 categories = 5 variables, which is ok. More info about One Hot Encoder : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/98174/101580

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out and let will let you know the improvement.

Comment: if I categorize whether I need to categorize with respect to occupancy also? like 06 -10 add all the occupancy as a single row ??

Comment: Yeah, just replace the 'arrival' value to as much columns you need to categorize it. Keep 1 line per sample you have of course, and don't touch 'occupancy'. For example, you know you have 1 sample giving x occupancy, you just want to summarize the information you have in your sample a way a model could understand, so you could give it "This info extracted from the sample gives x occupancy, learn from it".

Comment: df['time'] = pd.cut(pd.to_datetime(df.arrival).dt.hour,
       bins=[0, 6, 10, 14, 18, 24],
       labels=['00:00 - 06:00', '06:01 - 10:00', '10:01 - 14:00', '14:01 - 18:00', '18:01 - 23:59'],
       right=False,
       include_lowest=True)

print(df)

Am I doing the categorisation properly with this line of code, Can Proceed with the one hot encoder ??

Comment: I have done the one-hot encoding, So shall I use those there are 5 more variables added so  I can add them to the model directly like total of 10 variables right?

Comment: I have tried what you have said but the model is performing even worse, Kindly have a look and give me some ideas. https://deepnote.com/project/Untitled-Python-Project-[link](D6jNHahzTyCIYd_OcsM0bw/%2FUntitled1.ipynb/#00001-4521e45a-7d28-44c8-a93a-df77d1e14f64)